# include text in XML tags for Substring

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

A bit new to XSLT, 
I have a scenario where I need to substring a text from XML, But I need to also consider the tags for substring . Here is an example.

```
 <ABCGEFGH>
   <SYSTEMINFO>2432048324884329</SYSTEMINFO>
   <PARENT>0000001200003100569DDA0000000000000000080595</PARENT>
   <DETAIL>007542038808460056</DETAIL>
 </ABCGEFGH>
```

XSLT I am trying

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- get the Operation Name from the request message -->
    <xsl:variable name="msgString" select="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="messageName" select="substring-after(substring-before($msgString,'>'),'&lt;')"/>
    <TEST>
        <xsl:value-of select="$messageName"/>
    </TEST>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
 <TEST>ABCDEFG</TEST>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Expected Output <TEST>ABCDEFG</TEST>

Answer (score 2):

Before XSLT gets to work on an XML document, that document has to be parsed into a Document Object Model, and this model has no knowledge of angled brackets. These are only present in the "lexical" XML which you view when viewing the XML as text.

XSLT will deal with nodes (elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions). Your `msgString` variable refers to the root element `ABCGEFGH` in your XML, and not a string. If you attempt to do string functions on it, XSLT will use the text value of that node.

What you need to do is simply this...

```
<TEST>
    <xsl:value-of select="name($msgString)"/>
</TEST>
```

You probably want to rename `msgString` to something else like `msgNode` to avoid confusion as to what it contains.

Comment: That worked, Thanks a lot Tim for the swift response.